# How to calculate forces (Hooke's law) efficiently?

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph, physics, nodes

I'm trying to optimize a [force-directed graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-directed_graph_drawing). So far I have implemented it using the naïve O(n<sup>2</sup>) method. It can only handle around 1000 nodes, which is far too few for my needs.

[image]

Those of you familiar with the algorithm know that it has two main components: repulsion between nodes in Coulomb's law fashion and spring-like attraction along edges using Hooke's law, both of these components involve pairwise calculations between nodes.

The Barnes-Hut algorithm works nicely for the former which would bring the repulsion component to O(n log n). However I have not been able to find something similar for the spring component. I have considered the following:

1. Dividing the nodes based on location into overlapping bins and performing pairwise calculations only between nodes in the same bin. However, this might not work in all cases, especially since the initial configuration of the nodes is random and connected nodes could be anywhere. I could change how I generate the nodes but unless they are all in the same bin it would still produce incorrect results.
2. Storing the edges separately and iterating through them to calculate the spring forces. Right now this looks to be the most promising method to me.

Is there a better way I haven't considered? If it matters at all, I'm using C# and it'd be nice if it were trivial to throw in a parallel loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I implemented what I described in my second case and it worked well. I maintained and iterated through a collection of neighbours for each node, which allowed the entire acceleration routine to be easily parallelized (along with Barnes-Hut). Overall time complexity is O(max(n log n, k)) where k is the total number of edges. My C# implementation handles around 100000 nodes and 150000 edges at an acceptable level of performance.

Answer (score 0):

I feel the second option that you gave should work with linear complexity in terms of the number of edges. Just iterate through them and keep updating the resultant forces on the respective 2 nodes.

EDIT: Sorry I earlier thought that each node is connected to every other node through a spring.

Comment: This is a useful property but I don't see how applies to my problem. Each edge is a distinct spring so you can't really model two edges as one.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you have O(n log n) for the repulsion component and the attraction component is sparse: for each node you have on average k << n spring-like attractions. If so you can take care of the attraction component in O(n * k) by storing attraction in adjacency list instead of adjacency matrix.